# Why I don't see event subscriptions when using Event Hub + Event Grid?

Tags: azureportal, azure-eventgrid

I have the following setup:

- Event Hub with capture feature enabled
- Event Grid with an event subscription added from Event Hub to an Azure Function

my concern is that everything works fine, I cannot see any subscription added to the Event Grid instance(metrics are also not available by the way).

Is this because of the fact, that Event Hub + Event Grid are in Central US and Function App is hosted in West Europe?

Comment: It looks like that the current preview version of the Event Grid doesn't have a completely UI support on the portal, especially for Event Hub, see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-event-grid-now-supports-event-hubs-as-a-destination/ where can be done using CLI command. Also, I can see, the EventGridTrigger Function doesn't have a capability to manage already created subscriptions. On the other hand, the Blob Storage and Custom Topic have a list of the subscriptions on the portal for their editing purposes.

Comment: Yeah but for my purpose I'm using a standard `HttpTrigger`. What is somehow misleading is the fact, that for Functions metrics are displayed correctly(if added directly from an Event Grid instance), while the same subscription integrated with Event Hub is somehow missing.